# access flash object methods using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am dealing with music player, i try to access this players method like play, pause, top using java script. but the code can't control those methods. can anyone tell a method for access stop,play and pause method of this using java script or jQuery
Thank you

Here is my code

```
<div class="audiojs" classname="audiojs" id="audiojs_wrapper0">
    <object width="1" height="1" style="position: absolute; left: -1px;" name="audiojs0" id="audiojs0"
            classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
        <param value="./audiojs/audiojs.swf?playerInstance=audiojs.instances['audiojs0']&amp;datetime=1336309077444.049"
               name="movie">
        <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
        <embed width="1" height="1" allowscriptaccess="always"
               src="./audiojs/audiojs.swf?playerInstance=audiojs.instances[%27audiojs0%27]&amp;datetime=1336309077444.049"
               name="audiojs0">
    </object>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To access JavaScript functions from your ActionScript class you can make use of the `ExternalInterface` method.

On the HTML page where your SWF is embedded, you will have to include the custom JavaScript functions you want to access from your SWF. With the help of the `ExternalInterface` method you can access any declared JavaScript function.

In your case, just wrap the stop , play and pause function of the music player in a custom JavaScript function (which you can then address from the SWF) or call the native stop, play and pause function directly. I prefer to create a wrapper class so that your code is understandable for any third party.

The principle is very easy to implement, just read through [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html) link and you will be on your way!

Comment: thanks i prefer js of this swf and found those methods now its working.. when i stop the music and then play, the whole file loads again. can you know the reason for this..

Comment: Maybe you could try to use the pause function instead of the stop function? So when the user presses play, the song just resumes from it's paused position?